# WPF, Using a user control from another project is throwing an error

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a WPF project and my MainView loads fine.  I can add controls onto my view with no issue.  In one of my controls I reference a control from an outside project (which is referenced in this project) and the XAML sees the correct items when I add that control into the XAML.  That control is in a WPF Custom Controls Library.  However, every time I run it I get this error.

Could not load file or assembly 'xxxControl, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot file the file specified.

I'm at a loss on this as I've done this in the past.  The project is x64 and I made the control x64 as well.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.LayoutViews.ColorScaleItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             **xmlns:testC="clr-namespace:TestControl;assembly=TestControl"**
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Views.LayoutViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="20"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <testC:TestControl1 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></testC:TestControl1>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Does the control depend on any other assemblies? It's possible that those aren't present in your Debug/Release directory.

Comment: I've taken it down to the base level where the control I'm adding is nothing more that a UserControl that contains a rectangle...

Answer (score -1):

Please check the .NET framework you are using for those projects. Be sure you have higher/newer or equal version used by your consumer app, where the other is being referenced.